# iOS7 RMMapView can't load all the tiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mapbox

I am using MapBox SDK, and i have already generated my .mbtiles file.
But when i am using it with a RMMapView, it can only load a little of them. Why not all the tiles are loaded?
For example, there should be a 16 tiles in zoomlevel 0, but i can only see 2.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nn" ofType:@"mbtiles"]]];
    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];

    // default zoom
    mapView.zoom = 0;
    // hard code minimal zoom. Try to run in without it to see what happens.
    mapView.minZoom = 0;
    mapView.maxZoom = 3;
    // hide MapBox logo
    mapView.showLogoBug = NO;
    // hide bottom right "i" icon
    [mapView setHideAttribution:YES];

    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES; // these tiles aren't designed specifically for retina, so make them legible

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you generate the MBTiles file? Have you tried it in another client, such as uploading to mapbox.com? You can also set breakpoints in `RMMBTilesSource` to see if tiles are being loaded.